# Passing class Object refrence to another class then trying to use it is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, nsobject

I am trying to pass a reference of my current NSObject Class through two other object classes so I can access the current initialization of the original NSObject class I called from.

I will try to outline why I am doing this in as simply as possible. I have 3 NSObject Classes and an appDelegate.

1. AppDelegate
2. RemoteSites
3. EngineRequest
4. EngineReasponse

This is the logical flow of the app as it stands

```
Appdelegate.m
calls RemoteSites method "GetRemoteSites" this method reutrns a BOOL for confirmation

RemoteSites.m
-(BOOL)GetRemoteSites {
// calls EngineRequests method like so
EngineRequests *engineRequests = [[EngineRequests alloc] init];
[engineRequests GetRemoteSites:self];

//..
}

EngineRequests.m

- (void)GetRemoteSites:(NSObject *)myObjectClass {
 // get everything ready to send off request
}

send off request then return recived data + NSObject refrence to EngineReasponse

EngineReasponse.m
- (void)GetRemoteSites:(NSData *)receivedData Object:(NSObject *)requestingClass
{
// pass requestingClass to a NSObject var that will later be used to pass the data back to the original class that started the request
 requestingClassObject = requestingClass
}

//..
[requestingClassObject GetRemoteSitesNow:reducedDataPacket]; // GetremoteSitesNow is a method inside RemoteSites class, however using requestingClassObject I cannot see any of the classMethods my class has in it
//..
```

So thats the overall flow of the process I am trying to complete, the whole point is to try and get -(BOOL)GetRemoteSites to return Yes to the AppDelegate.

In summery my question stands as this. Why can I not access RemoteSites methods from EngineReasponse's, I have passed the class Object refrence correctly *I think* but for some reason I cannot access the methods.

Any help solving my issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual question here? The question in the title seems to have nothing to do with anything in the body of the question, but the body of the question doesn't actually ask a question. It's a little confusing. Maybe you need to focus on some particular aspect of the design that's confusing you?

Comment: What you're trying to do should work. Have you imported RemoteSites.h into EngineReasponse.m?

Comment: @rdelmar yes I have it #imported at the top of EngineReasponse.m

Comment: If you log requestingClassObject in EngineReasponse what do you get?

Comment: it returns this <GetRemoteSites: 0x1e886e20>

Comment: Hmmm... that's not right, it should return RemoteSites if you've passed it along properly.

Comment: okay ill go back through again and check.. by logging it at engineRequests etc. :P breb

Comment: okay so its wrong as soon as I send it which means there is something wrong with **[engineRequests GetRemoteSites:self];** getRemoteSites has a parameter of NSObject. RemoteSites is of type NSObject.. so that code should work right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33601/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-hurknburks)

Answer (score 1):

```
EngineRequests.m

- (void)GetRemoteSites:(id)remoteSites {
 // create your class object here or globally.  

RemoteSites *remotesite = (RemoteSites*)remoteSites

}

EngineReasponse.m

- (void)GetRemoteSites:(NSData *)receivedData Object:(id)requestingClass
{

RemoteSites *requestingClassObject = (RemoteSites*)requestingClass
}


//
[requestingClassObject GetRemoteSitesNow:reducedDataPacket]; 
//
```

Sorry for the typo.  Hope it will help.